# palabra o palabras en el buscador consulta sql con php

Tags: php, sql

Tengo un buscador. Aunque mi código trabaja bien, tiene un problema que quiero saber cómo se puede resolver.

```
    $frase = explode(" ",$buscador);
    $numero = count($frase);
    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE id";
    
    foreach($frase as $words){
        if($numero == 1) {
    
    $query .= "AND titulo LIKE '%".$words."%' OR tema LIKE '%".$words."%'";
   } elseif ($numero>1) {

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $numero; $i++) 
    
    $query .= "AND titulo LIKE '%".$words."%' OR tema LIKE '%".$words."%'";
    
   } }
```

El usuario escribe una o varias palabras en el $buscador. A la $frase le paso un explode para saber de cuántas palabras se compone la frase y las cuento. Una primera parte de la consulta se aplicará independientemente del $número de palabras, que es el select. Con un foreach descompongo la frase, si es una palabra o varias palabras se ejecuta una segunda parte de la consulta. Hasta ahí bien, funciona muy bien. El problema está en que repite la segunda parte de la consulta según el número de palabras. Supongamos que busco: el cielo azul (tres palabras), al imprimirla me aparece así

Cuando es una palabra la segunda parte la repite dos veces

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE id 
AND titulo LIKE '%cielo%' OR tema LIKE '%cielo%'
AND titulo LIKE '%cielo%' OR tema LIKE '%cielo%'
```

Cuando son varias palabras

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE id 
AND titulo LIKE '%el%' OR tema LIKE '%el%'
AND titulo LIKE '%el%' OR tema LIKE '%el%'
AND titulo LIKE '%el%' OR tema LIKE '%el%'

AND titulo LIKE '%cielo%' OR tema LIKE '%cielo%'
AND titulo LIKE '%cielo%' OR tema LIKE '%cielo%'
AND titulo LIKE '%cielo%' OR tema LIKE '%cielo%'

AND titulo LIKE '%azul%' OR tema LIKE '%azul%'
AND titulo LIKE '%azul%' OR tema LIKE '%azul%'
AND titulo LIKE '%azul%' OR tema LIKE '%azul%'
```

Es decir, repite la segunda parte de la consulta según el número de palabras. Si el usuario pone muchas palabras se genera una consulta enorme, es un problema muy grande.

Alguien que pueda orientarme en este asunto

Comment: Creo que sería más conveniente buscar por [fulltext](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html), optimizando la consulta y, además, los resultados van a ser más apropiados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que tienes bucles de más, realmente basta con un bucle que vaya añadiendo elementos al $query pero en tu código repites esta operación para cada palabra, por eso sacas comparaciones redundantes
Prueba con esto

```
foreach($frase as $words){
          $query .= " AND titulo LIKE '%".$words."%' OR tema LIKE '%".$words."%'";
    }
```

Esto soluciona tu código, pero creo que existen otras formas de buscar más efectiva con MySQL.

Comment: Además ten en cuenta añadir un espacio antes del `AND` o al acabar la asignación de la variable `$query`. O Acabarás teniendo un ` WHERE idAND";`

Comment: Vaya, es cierto. basta con un bucle. no es necesario poner los if condicionales. no lo había pensado. Esta es la función básica y tenía ese problema. Pero ya resuelto puedo usar Match Again o cualquier otra forma de buscar. Gracias!